# c# Itextsharp copy content table / goto local page

Tags: c#, pdf, split, itext

I have a big problem and i hope you can help me out.

I have a PDF file which I split in more files.

Problem: There is a table content (goto page X), but in the new pdf files it doesnt work anymore.

I cant find a solution to copy this table content to the new pdf files.

For your understanding:
I have three pdf files which are equal.

PDF: 
Page 1: 
Text

Page 2: 
Contenttable: 
Content x Page 3 (Goto Page 3)
Content x Page 4 ""
content x Page 5 ""

...
...

I put all these pdf files together in one big pdf. (Content table still working)
And now, i will split these back in to single once (Content table not working)

My idea was to export the content table out of the original pdf(Where table content is still working) and to import it in the new once. 
But i dont know how.

Second idea: search for keywords in the PDF and change the keyword to an goto local page action.

But i find no solution how i can do this. 
However in the end i want to repair the table content in each single pdf file.

any ideas?

code so far:

```
 PdfReader reader = null;
 Document sourceDocument = null;
 Document remote = null;
 PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
 PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;
 PdfStamper stamp = null;
 Chunk chunk = null;

        reader = new PdfReader(path);
        Seitenanzahl = reader.NumberOfPages;
        sourceDocument = Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startpage));
        tmp = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, startpage);

        string[] strsplit = tmp.Split(' ');
        vorname = strsplit[4];
        nachname = strsplit[5];
        ort = strsplit[6];
        perso = strsplit[7];



        vorname = vorname.Replace("\n", "");
        vorname = vorname.Replace(" ", "");
        nachname = nachname.Replace("\n", "");
        nachname = nachname.Replace(" ", "");
        ort = ort.Replace("\n", "");
        ort = ort.Replace(" ", "");
        perso = perso.Replace("\n", "");
        perso = perso.Replace(" ", "");




        if (Directory.Exists("test/" + ort))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory("test/" + ort);
        }
        outputpdfpath = "test/" + ort + "/" + "p_" + ort + "_" + perso + "_" + vorname.ToLower() + "_" + nachname.ToLower() + "_hj1_booklet_2017" + ".pdf";





        pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument,
            new FileStream(outputpdfpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));

        sourceDocument.Open();



        for (int i = startpage; i <= endpage; i++)
        {
            importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

            pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
        }
        sourceDocument.Close();


        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Use `PdfStamper` and `selectPages()` instead of `PdfCopy`.

Comment: But i need my pdfcopy to add pages to the new document. How can i use the stamper to creater a new file? I thought the stamper has something to do with adding comments or bookmarks.

Comment: `PdfStamper` can also be used to make a selection of pages in an existing PDF (preserving stuff like bookmarks). If you need to add extra pages, you can insert pages. I don't know the exact context of your question, but as an alternative, you *can* take the existing bookmarks, adapt them, and insert them into a `PdfCopy` instance.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help so far. I think this is what i looking for. I hope so^^ But this is what i ask. How can i extract all bookmarks?

Comment: You are looking for the `SimpleBookmark` class. Check these examples: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/merging-documents-bookmarks

Comment: I dont know. I tried it a little bit. But dont have a solution yet. Is there no other way to copy the old pdf ? That i dont have to repair the new one? I thought this is simple code to split a pdf. How can a split a pdf without damaging the links, hyperlinks, bookmarks, contenttable? A full 1:1 copy but with less pages.

Comment: Well, I started by advising to use `PdfStamper` and `selectPages()`, but somehow that didn't seem as a valid option to you (and I don't know why you rejected that option). It's kind of hard helping people who reject options without clearly explaining why they reject them.

Comment: I dont know how to use these. I am not the best in c# and still learning. I thought the Pdfstamper is to edit a existing file and to place there a link etc. I did not know that stamper can extract something. Could you give me a little example how i can use it please?

Comment: I am a Java developer, not a C# developer; so I can only answer in Java. If you are still learning, I recommend using the official web site. See for instance [Reordering pages](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs-itext5/reordering-pages) where we use the `selectPages()` method to reorder pages. You can also use that method to extract a selection of pages (e.g. `reader.selectPages("1-3")`). As for inserting pages, see [How to add blank pages to an existing PDF in java?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-blank-pages-existing-pdf-java)

Comment: Once you can insert a blank page into an existing PDF using `PdfStamper`, you can also easily add content to that blank page. However, if you add the content of a `PdfImportedPage`, you will lose all interactivity of that specific page (while the interactivity of the pages of the original document will be preserved).

Comment: yes, thanks for your help. But ive been searching for a solution without losing something. Pdfstamper and selectedpage is only a other way to create a new document. I think there is only one way. To write single links in the new pdf and create a new content table. with chunks and action.